# GetRef to capture methods?

Tags: vbscript, methods, reference

I've just discovered VBScript's GetRef function, which gets a reference to the function named by its argument. Is there any way to get a reference to a method in this way? I have a hunch that VBScript doesn't offer the sophistication of binding needed to do so, but it would sure be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `GetRef` doesn't support class methods.

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround for this, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48618251/need-to-pass-object-and-operation-in-a-function-that-executes-it/48618743#48618743)

Here the full sample

```
Const forReading = 1, forWriting = 2, forAppending = 8, CreateFile = True
Set my_obj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile("c:\temp\test.txt", forWriting, CreateFile)

Function my_function(my_obj, method, text)
  command = "my_obj." & method & " """ & text & """"
  ExecuteGlobal command
End Function

'make a reference to our function
Set proc = GetRef("my_function") 
'and call it with parameters, the first being the method invoked
Call proc(my_obj, "WriteLine", "testing")

'cleanup'
my_obj.Close
Set my_obj = Nothing
```