# Need to pass object and operation in a function that executes it

Tags: vbscript, qtp, testcomplete

I need to pass an object and its operation in a function so that each time I can call the function only and save me to write same steps for all the objects like validating the object before performing an operation. Similar way to a Register User Function in QTP/UFT.

However, Testcomplete doesn't have this feature *(atleast under my knowledge, would be happy to know if there is)*

This is my code that I am trying but unable to:

```
Call OpenPageorTab("Aliases.Admin.wndMain.toolStrip", ".Visible")

Function OpenPageorTab(obj, method)

'if obj.Exists then
  execute a = obj&method
  delay(1000)
  OpenPageorTab = True
'Else
  log.Error "Unable to find the object"
  OpenPageorTab = False
'End if
```

*using if condition as i was passing object earlier instead of string*

It fails at "execute" statement and gives me VbScript runtime error when executing this statement. 
my question is two fold -

1. How do I pass objects and its operation in a function and execute it
2. Also is it possible to pass an object it self instead of string for ex:

`obtoolbar = "Aliases.Admin.wndMain.toolStrip"`

`Call OpenPageorTab(obtoolbar, ".Visible")`

Appreciate any help or direction on this issue

**EDIT 1**

I am somewhere close to an answer however not accurately. I am able to pass the object as string - Check the code below

```
Call OpenPageorTab("Aliases.Admin.wndMain.toolStrip", ".Click")


Function OpenPageorTab(obj, method)

' if obj.Exists then
    eobj = "" & obj & method
    execute (eobj)
    delay(1000)
    OpenPageorTab = True
' Else
    log.Error "Unable to find the object"
    OpenPageorTab = False
' End if

End Function
```

*However I still need to pass the object something like*

```
Set oToolStrip = Aliases.Admin.wndMain.toolStrip
Call OpenPageorTab(oToolStrip, ".Click")
```

This is something that I'm unable to do.

**EDIT 2**
I have already got the answer to this problem and have posted the solution. That being said, is there any way that Function can be utilized as a method ?

Comment: See the `Execute` or `ExecuteGlobal` command in VBScript. It allows you to add any statement to your current code while running. Statements outside of a sub or function are executed immediately. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/342311f1(v=vs.84).aspx

Comment: I'm already using execute here. The problem is that i need to pass an object and its operation within the function. work with string but how do i use it with objects ?

Comment: You write your function with your object and the method. That's what executeglobal does. You turn it in to programming text. As if you were writing it.

Comment: I'm sorry, i fail to understand what you meant by the above comment. did you check my EDIT 1 in the question ? - It works when i pass the object as a string but it fails if i pass the object itself.

Comment: I'm sorry, I speak English. I've been clear. Use Global execute and write the statement you want executed. Don't bother replying.

Comment: Found the solution, wasn't the executeglobal issue. thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here an example of how to reference a function and pass parameteers to it, including objects.

```
Const forReading = 1, forWriting = 2, forAppending = 8, CreateFile = True
Set my_obj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile("c:\temp\test.txt", forWriting, CreateFile)

Function my_function(my_obj, method, text)
  command = "my_obj." & method & " """ & text & """"
  ExecuteGlobal command
End Function

'make a reference to our function
Set proc = GetRef("my_function") 
'and call it with parameters, the first being the method invoked
Call proc(my_obj, "WriteLine", "testing")

'cleanup'
my_obj.Close
Set my_obj = Nothing
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, However I'm trying to pass operation/method along with object. Can you let me know if that can be achieved, incase I misunderstood or missed something from your answer here. so basically in your above example, i want to pass "my_obj" as Object and "WriteLine" as its method

Comment: Vbscipt has no send method like Ruby but you can do it like aCatinvolved suggested with ExecuteGlobal, execute or eval, I adapted my answer

Comment: you are using my_obj as string ("my_obj.") in command - how do you achieve the same incase you want to pass my_obj as is - like the object it is.

Comment: Thanks for your help Peter, based your answer I worked around to find a solution. Answer posted

Comment: you are welcome, to reply to your question: i don't pas myobj als a string but indeed as an abject, only to invoke the method passed in the function itself you need a string to be evaluted by execute

Comment: exactly. I realized later that my comment was naive. :)

Answer (score 0):

*I was able to finally formulate the solution the below function can work as makeshift register function in TestComplete*

```
Sub test

'Set the Object
Set pToolStrip = Aliases.Admin.wndMain.toolStrip.Button("User Admin")
Call GenericOperationFunc(pToolStrip, ".Click", "N")

'if you want to perform an operation which return a value
b = GenericOperationFunc(Aliases.Admin.wndPopup.Child(2), ".Caption", "Y")

End Sub

Public Function GenericOperationFunc(obj, method, Return)
   GenericOperationFunc = False
   on error resume next
   if obj.Exists then
      if Ret = "Y" then
          eobj = "NewText="&"obj" & method
          execute (eobj)
          GenericOperationFunc = NewText 
          Delay(500)
      Else
          eobj = "obj" & method
          execute (eobj)
          delay(1000)       
          GenericOperationFunc = True
      End if
  Else
      log.Error "Unable to find the object"
      GenericOperationFunc = False
  End if

End Function

'log.error, delay, aliases, ptoolstrip(object) are testcomplete specific
```